# Error when Dictionary count is bigger as 89478457

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I am getting on this command

```
Dictionary<UInt64, int> myIntDict = new Dictionary<UInt64, int>(89478458);
```

this error:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled  HResult=-2147024882
Message=Array dimensions exceeded supported range.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Initialize(Int32 capacity)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor(Int32 capacity, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
```

On 89478457 there is no error. Here is the source of Initialize in [Dictionary.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs):

```
    private void Initialize(int capacity)
    {
        int size = HashHelpers.GetPrime(capacity);
        ...
        entries = new Entry[size];
        ...
    }
```

When I reproduce this, the error happens on the array creation. Entry is a struct in this case with size 24. When we get max int32 (0x80000000-1) and divide on 24 = 89478485 and this number is between prime numbers 89478457 and 89478503.

Does this mean, that array of struct cannot be bigger as maxInt32/sizeOfThisStruct?

EDIT:

Yes. I actually go over 2 GB. This happens, when the dictionary creates the internal array of struct Entry, where are the (key,value) pairs stored. In my case the sizeof(Entry) is 24 bytes and as value type is inline allocated.

And the solution is to use the [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054)  flag (thank you [Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk)). Actually in .net core the flag is [the environment variable](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/clr-configuration-knobs.md#environmentregistry-configuration-knobs) COMPlus_gcAllowVeryLargeObjects (thank you [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick)).

And yes, [Paparazzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607314/paparazzi) is right. I have to think about, how not to waste memory.
Thank you all.

Comment: I wonder why you need dictionary that big in size? The real practicality of this ordeal is what I am questioning

Comment: @BenPhilipp Int is only for test. Actually is a struct.

Comment: @MukeshAdhvaryu What will you use for sparse 3d Array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is known limitation of .NET runtime - maximum object size allowed on the heap is 2 GB, even on 64-bit version of runtime. But, starting from .NET 4.5 there is [configuration option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows you to relax this limit (only on 64-bit version of runtime still) and create larger arrays. Example of configuration to enable that is:

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this work the same for .Net Core? I think .Net Core does not use app.config.

Comment: Thanks for information. Seems your link answers your question. I've tested and without that option behavior seems the same (so it also throws OutOfMemoryException when allocating too big array).

Comment: @Evk This has nothing to do with 2GB limit. I am far away from 2GB.

Comment: @Mottor No you are not far away from 2GB.  It needs contiguous memory.

Comment: @Mottor just apply that configuration change mentioned and see how exception goes away. This limit is not related to amount of memory you have - applies even if you have terabytes.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface Dictionary does not make sense
You can only have int unique values
Do you really have that my duplicates

UnInt32 goes to 4,294,967,295
Why are you wasting 4 bytes?

89,478,458 rows 
Currently a row is 12 bytes
You have 1 GB at about 83,333,333 rows
Since an object needs contiguous memory 1 GB is more of a practical limit

If values is really a strut 24
Then 1 gb in 31,250,000

That is just a really big collection

You can split is up into more than one collection

Or use a class as then it is just a reference with I think is 4 bytes

Comment: In the UInt64 is position in 3D Array (X,Y,Z) encoded, the value is the value in array. They are filled dynamic from the user (SQL) and the array is sparse. Then there are a lot of calculations.

Comment: Then I suggest more efficient encoding as you are wasting a lot of space.

Comment: It is with bit mask encoded. In the reality the normal size is between 100000 and 500000, but I should know where is the limit, because I do not know anything about the data at compile time.

Comment: So you don't know know the size.  It won't be an exact number as contiguous memory is effected by other factors. You are wasting a lot of space and all you seem to care about is throwing more memory at it.

Comment: And can you tell me your proposal? How to encode 3 int in one key bellow int64 size and they are fast to encode? And if you see the value, it is int and not struct 24 bytes. What 24 byte struct is the internal implementation of C# dictionary (click on the link) Elem struct.

Comment: Post a separate question. You really need three Int for position?  If sparce then again wasting memory.  Does not compute with 89478458 values - not even close.  Again looks to me like you are wasting a lot of space and  all you seem to care about is throwing more memory at it.